# Printing in Tamil in Bluetooth Printer for android

Tags: java, android

need sample android code for to print in tamil using bluetooth printer..
Am working with the following code but its printing only number and English char :( .. Printer feeds empty space when it try to print tamil char.. any new ideas will be appreciated..

```
mbtOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
mbtOutputStream.write(Command);
        String sendingmessage = "டெஸ்ட் கிரெடிட் பில்";
        byte[] send = sendingmessage.getBytes();
        mbtOutputStream.write(send);
        mbtOutputStream.write(FEED_LINE);
        mbtOutputStream.flush();
        thread.sleep(20);


        mbtOutputStream.write(as);
        sendingmessage = "   To Retailer:";
        send = sendingmessage.getBytes();
        mbtOutputStream.write(send);
        mbtOutputStream.flush();
        mbtOutputStream.write(FEED_LINE);
        thread.sleep(20);

        sendingmessage = "  No.25/6, டெக்னாலஜி  fund";
        send = sendingmessage.getBytes();
        mbtOutputStream.write(send);
        mbtOutputStream.flush();
        mbtOutputStream.write(FEED_LINE);
        thread.sleep(20);
```

any one please tell me how to feed tamil char to print in the printer...

Comment: Did you find any solution for printing tamil font?

Comment: still no Yashwanth :-( .. if u find anything means pls inform

Comment: Your printer needs to support Unicode character set or any codepage in Tamil. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_All_Character_Encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try `byte[] send = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(sendingMessage)`

Comment: This won't do unless the printer also supports UTF-8. (some portable thermal printers don't).